# DJANGO-SUMMERNOTE not working post value blank/null

Tags: django, summernote

I am having 2 issues with django summernote

everything is setup as it should be but it generally doesn't update the form [post data returns an empty string

1. Post data empty
2. images do upload to server but they wont update on the text area as they should so the image upload does not return results which is the main reason I opted for summernote

And the other thing is I am using django 1.3, but I soughted out compatibility issues where there was a need

Comment: It sounds like you should be writing this as a bug or issue on the [bug tracker](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote); rather than posting it here. Unless you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed there was a bug with the version its all done now